# Keep custom cursor when clicking a link using CSS

Tags: css, cursor

I use this css code to change my cursor to a custom image.

```
*
{
    cursor: url(../images/cursor.png), auto;
}
```

Now, whenever I click a link or a button, the cursor changes to the default one. How can I prevent it?

Comment: If you can make the code run, it is easier to debug.

Comment: I never used custom cursors so I'm not sure, but did you try setting the cursor for :active as well?

Comment: Yes, although I'm pretty sure * applies to all elements. Correct me if I'm wrong. Anyway, still won't work guys.

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply same css to that particular links too. e.g.

```
a {
 cursor: url(http://placehold.it/50x30) , auto;
}
```

In your case

```
a {
 cursor: url(../images/cursor.png), auto;
}
```

[working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pradeep1991singh/1wabhx1n/1/)

For more reference -

[Cursor](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/cursor/)

Comment: Thanks, but it's not what a meant. When you click the link, for half a second the cursor changes to the normal one.

Answer (score 0):

You mean the default cursor is shown if you click on a link, keep pressing it and move a bit around? This cannot be changed as this interaction causes the element (in this case a link) to be dragged around, which cannot be styled afaik.

edit: Yes, * applies to all element and will always override the browser defaults. So it's not a specificity problem.

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
.custom-cursor:link {
        cursor: url(../images/cursor.png), auto;
    }

.custom-cursor:hover {
        cursor: url(../images/cursor.png), auto;
    }

.custom-cursor:active {
        cursor: url(../images/cursor.png), auto;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<a href="YourLinkHere" class="custom-cursor">link visible text here</a>.
```

Add `class="custom-cursor"` to every link or button on which you want this behavior.